# Singleline #if #endif?

Tags: c#

is there a faster way in C# of

```
#if foo
  Something();
#endif
```

like pseudo-code:

```
#if(foo, DoThat(); )
```

im a programmer, and programmers are lazy ;-)

Comment: By *faster* did you mean *shorter* ?

Comment: yes, faster to write ;)

Comment: Typical C# team wisdom, code you should not use should be hard to write.  And stand out like a sore thumb, the missing indenting warns the reader.  [POLA is important](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's nothing which lets you write an `#if ... #endif` on a single line.

If `Something` should *only* ever be called if `FOO` is defined, then you can decorate it with [`ConditionalAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute?view=netframework-4.8):

```
[Conditional("FOO")]
public void Something()
{
   ...
}
```

If you do this, the compiler will remove all calls to `Something` unless `FOO` is defined.

---

It's also a good idea to try and keep all `#ifs` in a single place, rather than interspersed through your code. As well as making it easier to see how the behaviour of your application changes depending on what conditional compilation symbols are defined, it also removes the `#if` noise from most of your code.

It may also make sense to have entirely different versions of the same file for different targets (e.g. `Thing.Foo.cs` and `Thing.cs`), and specify in your csproj file which one should be included, based on conditions.

---

Finally, remember that the point of code is to be read and understood: focus on writing clear and understandable code, rather than code which takes the shortest amount of time to write. You're going to spend a lot longer reading your code than writing it in the long run.

Comment: and thoose #ifs in my code are debugging and tracing stuff, on the start and end of functions.

Comment: @Crimson In that case, maybe it makes sense to mark your debugging and tracing methods with `[Conditional("FOO")]`? That way you can just call them regardless, without any `#ifs`, and the compiler will remove them if necessary. For example, your debugging stuff might include calls to [`Debug.Assert`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/diagnostics/Debug.cs,97), which is decorated with `[Conditional("DEBUG")]`.

Comment: yes, added the [conditional...] . Your answer is a real good solution!